# HTML 5 video and audio not playing in jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, video, jetty

i am using **jetty server** in eclipse, while adding videos with my jsp page it returns 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' error in chrome browser. my **sample.jsp** is like this...

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">

    <video width="800" controls>
      <source rc="<c:url value="/static/videos/tom.mp4"/>" type="video/mp4"></source>
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    <img height="400" src="<c:url value="/static/videos/title.jpg"/>" alt="First Slide">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

in this sample.jsp **tom.mp4 and title.jpg** are in the same folder only. while running this jsp file, image works properly but tom.mp4 file doesn't work.
**http://localhost:9192/pjt-web/static/videos/tom.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**  error. how can i play this video in this page?.

Comment: have you tried accessing the video with a direct reference in your browser?  does it return 404 then too?  Also, what was the URL that the browser used in an attempt to request to the video when you requested sample.jsp (check your network tab in your browser inspection tools while requesting sample.jsp)

Comment: when i tried outside of my project ,that video plays well... using (http://localhost:9192/pjt-web/static/videos/tom.mp4)only its never playing

Answer (score 0):

Got it!.. just added file extension in my **web.xml** file.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.mp4</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another way for IE.

After I created the jsp file in Eclipse, I put the mp4 file in the WebContent folder. And I added one line of code to run it.

```
    <embed src="./YourMovie.mp4" showcontrols="true" width="425" height="350"></embed>
```

[image]

---

it worked properly on the Tomcat 8.0 server.
[image]

---

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Movie -->
    <embed src="./mang.mp4" showcontrols="true" width="425" height="350"></embed>

</body>
</html>
```

Original source: http://dimdim.tistory.com/entry/%EC%9B%B9%ED%8E%98%EC%9D%B4%EC%A7%80-%EB%8F%99%EC%98%81%EC%83%81-Player-%EC%82%BD%EC%9E%85-%EB%B0%A9%EB%B2%95